# extendBodyBehindAppBar breaks ScrollController attachment?

Tags: flutter

I have to animate the app bar on one of the screens and I can't seem to make it work widgets to work.

Basically I want to use a `ListView` and `AnimatedBuilder` wrapped into a Scaffold with `extendBodyBehindAppBar` set to `true` - I want an image to be displayed behind the app bar.

[image]

The thing is, I'm consistently (and accross multiple platforms - web and Android) getting an error about the `ScrollController` not being attached to a widget. Am I doing something wrong or is it perhaps a Flutter bug?

Can I fix it somehow?

**Relevant widget:**

```dart
class _TestScreenState extends State<TestScreen> {
  final controller = ScrollController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(56),
        child: AnimatedBuilder(
          animation: controller,
          builder: (_, __) => AppBar(
            title: Text(controller.offset.toString()),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        controller: controller,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => SizedBox(
          height: 32,
          child: Text(index.toString()),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Full example:** 
https://dartpad.dev/?id=82c113b4c5471dd33961f8c07b750015 
https://gist.github.com/eEQK/82c113b4c5471dd33961f8c07b750015

**Stack trace:**

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown building AnimatedBuilder(animation: ScrollController#2b8e3(no clients), dirty, state: _AnimatedState#548ce):
ScrollController not attached to any scroll views.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_controller.dart':
package:flutter/…/widgets/scroll_controller.dart:1
Failed assertion: line 107 pos 12: '_positions.isNotEmpty'

Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=2_bug.md

The relevant error-causing widget was
AnimatedBuilder
package:playground/main.dart:30
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#2      ScrollController.position
package:flutter/…/widgets/scroll_controller.dart:107
#3      ScrollController.offset
package:flutter/…/widgets/scroll_controller.dart:115
#4      _TestScreenState.build.<anonymous closure>
package:playground/main.dart:33
```

[image]

Comment: You can use SliverAppBar I think

Answer (score 0):

Initially when you are accessing controller.offset, you are still inside build method and controller hasn't been attached to the listview.

You have passed ScrollController object as AnimationController in your app bar. Maybe you can create a ValueNotifer and pass it instead to AnimatedBuilder as it is done here

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedBuilder-class.html

Comment: `you are still inside build method and controller hasn't been attached to the listview` - but it works when you remove `extendBodyBehindAppBar: true` which doesn't make sense

Comment: Not sure why it may not work otherwise. As per solid principle, we should not care about the implementation. It could be changed any time. What we know for sure is offset property can only be set once ScrollController is attached to ListView. In normal case, it would be happening so. Now, when you give your ValueNotifer, you are sure that there is always some value passed to app bar hence even if implementation changes, the code won't break.

Comment: Adding to my last comment, it should not work in case of normal scaffold if it's not working in case of extendbodybehindappbar. You can raise an issue on flutters GitHub.